# I want to add List view below some of my components

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I am new in android and i am trying to add list view under some of my controls. I am not getting it how to do this. And i have already used Scroll view in xml as controls are more. So plz any one can help me out of this.? Thanks in advanced. I put link of my xml . [1](http://pastebin.com/8y8kLm21)[here]

Comment: By under means inside or below?

Comment: Show us the XML of what you've tried so far

Comment: means in my xml there are some controls over der. So how to display my list view under that. Under means below...

Comment: You want the list view within the scroll view or outside it?

Comment: @ Mohit: Within. If possible otherwise outside

Comment: I paste link of my xml above. In body

Comment: It would be good if you could put up a image of what you are try to achieve. Your code seems to complex and may be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

To add ListView to your Project, use the following code in your **java** file.

```
  String lv_arr[]={"Lamborghini","Audi","Ferrari","BMW"};  // add componenets here

    final ListView lst = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    lst.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));

   lst.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

            if(((position))==0) {
                //Any code you want e.g start a new activity
                               startActivity(new Intent(this, xyz.class);
        }
    }
  });
```